# Azure Active Directory: returning restricted claims set when creating new claim mapping policy (New-AzureADPolicy)?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I've been looking at this tutorial and found some other documentation on how to create a claim mapping policy that will return restricted claim sets. I'm using the preview version of the azure AD module for PowerShell with this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-claims-mapping#claims-mapping-policy-properties

I upgraded my PowerShell and installed the preview module. Created a policy as per the tutorial. Seems pretty easy but the documentation is lacking on how to return a specific claim set.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0-preview#policies

It's somewhat ambiguous as to whether you can, or cannot pass back this information.

Has anyone ever tried to return restricted claim sets before?

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":    {"Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true"}}') -DisplayName "AllTheClaims” -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

I'm assuming within that command line, there would be a parameter within the JSON definition to include restricted claims set. Again, I'm trying to scour the internet for answers. Any information would help,  thanks.

Comment: Claims in the restrictedclaimset cannot be added to a token